# How to get the scene coordinates of a Node in JavaFX 8? localToScene does not seem to work

Tags: java, javafx

The (Scala) code below produces a wrong result (namely `[x = 0.0, y = 0.0]`).

Why ?

How can it be fixed ?

According to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScene%28javafx.geometry.Point2D%29) this code should print `50, 80` for the `x` and `y` coordinates of `Circle`.

```
object CircleTestLauncher extends App{
  Application.launch(classOf[CircleTest])
}
class CircleTest extends Application with App
{
  override def start(p1: Stage): Unit = {

    val c1= new Circle(50,80,10)
    val sp=new Group

    sp.getChildren.add(c1)
    p1.setScene(new Scene(sp,300,300))
    p1.show()
    println("in start method, scene coord. of circle ="+c1.localToScene(Point2D.ZERO))

  }
}
```

prints:

```
in start method, scene coord. of circle =Point2D [x = 0.0, y = 0.0]
```

EDIT :

The accepted answer solves the problem, however, according to [this](http://blog.crisp.se/2012/08/29/perlundholm/window-scene-and-node-coordinates-in-javafx) blog entry my solution should work too, the question remains: **why does the above code not work ?**

What is the difference between the two coordinates (getCenter vs localToScene) ?

What is localToScene used for at all ?

I googled for this and found very few info on this.

JavaFX books also don't explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about how it is done in Scala, but in java, the following code works fine

```
System.out.println("X :" +c1.getCenterX()+ " Y: "+c1.getCenterY());
```

The output is

```
X :50.0 Y: 80.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for the **why** (this answer I found in the JavaFX 8 source code).

The reason is that local2Scene applies to **transformations only**.

So the actual position of a circle is its centre plus transformations (the centre coordinate vector multiplied by the transformation matrix).

```
object CircleTestLauncher extends App{
  Application.launch(classOf[CircleTest])
}

class CircleTest extends Application with App
{
  override def start(p1: Stage): Unit = {

    val c1= new Circle(50,80,10)
    val sp=new Group

    sp.getChildren.add(c1)
    c1.setTranslateX(10)
    c1.setTranslateY(20)
    p1.setScene(new Scene(sp,300,300))
    p1.show()
    println("in start method, scene coord. of circle ="+c1.localToScene(Point2D.ZERO))

  }
}
```

Prints:

```
in start method, scene coord. of circle =Point2D [x = 10.0, y = 20.0]
```